# How to capture text between a specific word and the semicolon immediately preceding it with regex?

Tags: regex, vba

I have many rows of people and titles in Excel, and am looking to filter out certain people by title. For example, cells may contain the following:

```
John Smith, Co-Founder;Jane Doe, CEO;James Jackson, Co-Founder
```

These cells are varying lengths and have varying numbers of people and titles. My plan is to add semicolons at the beginning and end to standardize it. This would give me:

```
;John Smith, Co-Founder;Jane Doe, CEO;James Jackson, Co-Founder;
```

Currently, I have a code that can iterate through and uses the following regex `Founder.*?;` which will return each instance of founder based on my code (i.e. `Founder;Founder;`) but the trouble is that I can't seem to figure out how to also capture the names of the people. I would think I would need to designate the semicolon immediately preceding "Founder" but so far I have not been able to get this. My ultimate goal would be to return something like the following, which I have the code for with the exception of the correct regular expression.

```
;John Smith, Co-Founder;James Jackson, Co-Founder;
```

Comment: Is it always Name; Position; Name; Position etc...? If so you could simply use the `SPLIT` function

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Excel, you could also do this with a formula:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'Co-Founder')]")
```

However, for a regex, you could use

```
(?:^|;)([^;]*?Co-Founder)
```

which will return the Co-Founders in capturing group 1.

There is no need for leading/trailing semicolons.

Even though VBA regex does not support look-behind, you can work with that limitation.

### the Co-Founders Regex

```
(?:^|;)([^;]*?Co-Founder)
```

Options: Case sensitive (or not, as you prefer); ^$ match at line breaks

- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:^|;)`

  - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `^`

    - [Assert position at the beginning of the string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
  - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `;`

    - [Match the character “;” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `;`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `([^;]*?Co-Founder)`

  - [Match any character that is NOT a “;”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `[^;]*?`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
  - [Match the character string “Co-Founder” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Co-Founder`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: @Baconator17 Ron wrote a helpful and well explained answer; it's good use at SO to accept it as preferred answer by ticking the green checkmark to indicate other users that you found it helpful :+)

Answer (score 0):

Split the whole string combined with a positive filtering and the `getCoFounders()` function will return an array of findings:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    Dim s As String
    s = ";John Smith, Co-Founder;Jane Doe, CEO;James Jackson, Co-Founder;"
    Debug.Print Join(getCoFounders(s), "|")
End Sub
```

```
Function getCoFounders(s As String)
getCoFounders = Filter(Split(s, ";"), "Co-Founder", True, vbTextCompare)
End Function
```

**Results in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
John Smith, Co-Founder|James Jackson, Co-Founder
```